# While read loop appending

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have  to extract lines from `file1` corresponding to a list of words in `file2`

I'm wondering what's the difference between doing:

```
while read line; do grep "${line}" file1; done < file2 > output

while read line; do grep "${line}" file1 >> output; done < file2
```

Which one is the correct and fatest?

Is there any other faster way of doing this than a loop?

Both the files I'm working are huge `536864856` and `1947` lines for `file1` and `file2`, respectively.

file1 (look a $7)

```
NC_045027.1     29500101        T/A     NC_045027.1:29500101    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2764     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500102        G/A     NC_045027.1:29500102    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2763     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500103        C/A     NC_045027.1:29500103    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2762     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500104        C/A     NC_045027.1:29500104    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2761     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500105        A/C     NC_045027.1:29500105    C       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2760     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500106        A/C     NC_045027.1:29500106    C       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2759     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500107        G/A     NC_045027.1:29500107    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2758     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500108        T/A     NC_045027.1:29500108    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2757     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500109        G/A     NC_045027.1:29500109    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2756     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_045027.1     29500110        G/A     NC_045027.1:29500110    A       101232882       XM_032744187.1  Transcript     3_prime_UTR_variant                                 2755     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       ARL14EPL        -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285707.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7416     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285715.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7234     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285720.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7110     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285728.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        6856     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285733.2  Transcript      intron_variant                                             --       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -       -      ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz                  --
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285738.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        6637     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285750.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        6348     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16147   C/A     NC_044998.1:16147       A       100221041       XM_030285760.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7209     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16148   A/C     NC_044998.1:16148       C       100221041       XM_030285707.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7415     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
NC_044998.1     16148   A/C     NC_044998.1:16148       C       100221041       XM_030285715.2  Transcript      3_prime_UTR_variant                                        7233     -       -       -       -       -       MODIFIER        -       -1      -       LOC100221041    -       -      -                                                   ZFgenomic_tabixprep_nomiRNA.gff.gz       -       -
```

file2

```
XM_032744187.1
XM_030272916.2
XM_032747381.1
XM_030265061.2
XM_030271469.2
XM_030272412.2
XM_032747456.1
```

Comment: `Which one is the correct and fatest`  - First one as it would output file only once, however this can be done using `grep -f file2 file1 > output`

Comment: IMHO if you could show samples of your files then I am pretty sure this could be done with a single awk should be faster than your current method too.

Comment: Both will be extremely slow and potentially mangle your data (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) as well as producing false positives due to partial matches and matches on  the wrong part of the data. If you reduce your example to a [mcve] where we don't need scrollbars to see it then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: The fact that you say `look a $7` tells us you already know that you should be using awk for this so it's not clear why you're asking about 2 shell loop + grep solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
while read line; do grep "${line}" file1; done < file2 > output

while read line; do grep "${line}" file1 >> output; done < file2
```

> Which one is the correct and fastest?

First one as it would open output file only once whereas `>> output` inside the loop would open output file for each line in `file2`.

> Is there any other faster way of doing this than a loop?

Based on updated information in question, this `awk` will produce accurate matching result which won't be possible with `grep -fF`. `awk` would be pretty fast too as we are reading only smaller file's first column in memory before doing a non-regex string comparison against `$7` from second file:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} $7 in seen' file2 file1 > output
```

Answer (score 1):

No loop:  `grep -f file2 file1`

You might consider `grep -Ff file2 file1` with `-F` for fixed strings.  If your `file2` is not regexes, but plain text, using `-F` can speed things up for large inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The first will erase any contents that `output` might have had before the command was run.

Also, the first will open the file only once. The second will re-open the file each time the `grep` command is run. This might be important if you for example expect the file to be moved while the command is running. If you don’t need to worry about this situation, you should prefer the first version: it will be slightly faster, as it won’t have to perform directory lookups over and over.

There is no way to say which one is ‘correct’ without knowing what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

For that task, fgrep is your friend.  The man page for fgrep looks fairly clear so I won't repeat.  Here you would say

```
fgrep -x -f file1 file2 > output
```

(the -x option forces fgrep to match only entire lines.)

Comment: Almost suggested `-x` with grep, however OP mentions `file2` is "words."   Also, `fgrep` seems to be an alias of sorts for `grep -F`

Comment: @stevesliva `fgrep` is the old, deprecated tool that has been replace by `grep -F`.